# Can Two Fonts (hieroglyphs) Be Stacked On The Same Line In A Reflowable ePUB?

Tags: css, fonts, epub

Windows 10 64-bit, InDesign CC 2107

I'm assembling a reflowable ePUB 3.0. for iBooks, which contains hieroglyphs, using the JSesh true type font. In some instances throughout the book, these characters are stacked, one on top of the other. I'd like to keep these as live fonts, but have been unable to come up with a way to do this. My first attempt was to create a small, single row, 2 column table, but regardless of size, the table loads on the very next line. I need it to stay on the same line as the text before and after, like it's all part of the sentence. Then I tried converting the two fonts to outlines, grouped them and inserted them inline. This does work, but they get converted to PNG upon export, which means the color can't change if iBooks' background is changed (ei: black bg - white text). Then I tried using a separate CSS to adjust the baseline, via span tags, just to see if I could get the font lifted upwards, but iBooks is ignoring: baseline-shift: 0.5em;

Any ideas? The 1st screenshot is how it looks as fonts in InD. The 2nd one is after converting to outlines and loaded inline, which is how I need it to look.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU8Al.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7er0c.jpg)

Comment: I've not worked with epub but would something like this work? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZedvpK

Comment: You should show some piece(s) of HTML and CSS code to show what you have tried. The odds are that this can be done e.g. with relative positioning, but the results will probably depend on the e-book readers.

Comment: Looked at MC's css inline-flex. Tried removing <i> and it stopped working; not sure why. Tried his CSS on mine-doesn’t work, with <i> or not. I'm proofing in Chrome and iBooks. I thought about relative pos, but will that keep it in the right place within the rest of the text flow? I thought it might drift, if user changes text size - increase or decrease. Not sure where to make it relative too. The xhtml and css is here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/06snu3y01ufxei7/AADZ8q5p-kgFfpihDrOpO_Zja?dl=0

Comment: So I banged on MC's suggestion some more and now it works! I'm previewing in iBooks and it looks fine! Thanks again for both of your input